# encode the given byte array such that the output has only small alphabets

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I am new to encryption and encoding/decoding. I want to encrypt and encode the given string so that the result string is only of small alphabets (not capital letters, numbers or any special characters?). Base64 is used for encoding. is that possible to acheive encoding using Base64 and get result strings only of small characters. If not which encryption method could give such results? thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to limit character set to small letters only? What's wrong with capital letters?

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Base64 requires both uppercase and lowercase. If you throw away the uppercase characters it becomes a very non-standard Base38 encoding, which also takes up more space. Why you would want to do such a thing remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

```
public byte [] encode (byte [] data)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
    for (byte b: data)
    {
        output.write ((b & 0x0F) + 'a');
        output.write ((((b >>> 4) & 0x0F) + 'a');
    }
    return output.toByteArray ();
}

public byte [] decode (byte [] encodedData)
{
    int l = encodedData.length / 2;
    byte [] result = new byte [l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        result [i] = 
            (byte)(
                encodedData [l * 2] - 'a' + 
                ((encodedData [l * 2 + 1] - 'a') << 4)
            );
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only lower case letters, it wouldn't be [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) anymore.
If your alphabet consists of only 16 lower case chars you could call it base16. And map each nibble (4 bit) to one of the chars.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor#encrypt()`.

The resulted encrypted text is encoded **BASE64** and thus safely stored as US-ASCII chars.

Answer (score 0):

[Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) uses single-case characters, therefore it should be suitable for your purpose. There is a [Base32 implementation](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html) from Apache Commons that you could use, or you could just write your own.

But why do you want to restrict your output to lower case only?